# Map error: wrong number of parameters

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark programming and i got stuck while using map.
My data Rdd contains.

```
 Array[(String, Int)] = Array((steve,5), (bill,4), (" amzon",6), (flikapr,7))
```

and while using again map i am getting below mentioned error .

```
data.map((k,v) => (k,v+1))
<console>:32: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
              data.map((k,v) => (k,v+1))
```

I am trying to pass a tuple with key value and wants to get back a tuple with 1 + to value.
Please help , why i am getting error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. rdd.map() operates on each record of the RDD and in your case, that record is a tuple. You can simply access the tuple members using Scala's underscore accessors like this:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Array(("steve",5), ("bill",4), ("amzon",6), ("flikapr",7)))

data.map(t => (t._1, t._2 + 1))
(steve,6)
(bill,5)
(amzon,7)
(flikapr,8)
```

Or better yet, use Scala's powerful pattern matching like this:

```
data.map({ case (k, v) => (k, v+1) }).foreach(println)
(steve,6)
(bill,5)
(amzon,7)
(flikapr,8)
```

Here's the best so far -- key-value tuples are so common in Spark that we usually refer to them as PairRDDs and they come with plenty of convenience [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions). For your use case, you only need to operate on the value without changing the key. You can simply use mapValues():

```
data.mapValues(_ + 1).foreach(println)
(steve,6)
(bill,5)
(amzon,7)
(flikapr,8)
```

Comment: Thank you @Junjun Olympia for this complete information. I need to work on my pattern matching.  PairRdd functions are really helpful for me.